# How to set busybox as login shell of a user?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, login, busybox

I customized my `BusyBox` to include some specific applets. Now I want a user login to `BusyBox` as its shell. I mean when that when user enters its username and passwords, he will bed redirected to an environment that only my desired applets are usable. Changing login shell of the user using following command does not work:

```
usermod -s /bin/busybox MYUSER
```

using `su MYUSER` only shows `BusyBox` help but I need an interactive shell includes only my desired applets. Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`busybox` command isn't an interactive shell. As Thomas said, you should run `busybox sh` for its interactive shell. Use these commands to set busybox interactive shell as login shell of user *MYUSER*:

```
echo "/bin/busybox sh" > /bin/ibusybox
chmod +x /bin/ibusybox
usermod -s /bin/ibusybox MYUSER
```

Also using `ibusybox` will run busybox interactive shell.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to start `busybox` with `sh` as parameter. Best would be to write a little wrapper:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/share/busybox
echo "/bin/busybox sh" > /usr/local/share/busybox/sh
chmod +x /usr/local/share/busybox/sh
```

Then test the login:

```
su - -s /usr/local/share/busybox/sh wood
```

If successful you can add `/usr/local/share/busybox/sh` as the user's shell.

```
usermod -s /usr/local/share/busybox/sh MYUSER
```

I quickly tried to symlink `busybox` to `/usr/local/share/busybox/sh` but that did not work. So therefore the wrapper script.

Comment: Cannot execute /usr/local/share/busybox/sh: Permission denied

Comment: Forgot to mention to make it executable. Updated the answer.